# What type of hard drives can be used in storage server

Tags: hard-drive, nas, storage, array

First of all  i am not asking for any shopping Recommendation but i want to know about this product on ebay

http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Hitachi-DF600-RKAJAT-Hard-Drive-Array-15x-Slots-500V-Storage-Unit-S19-09-/221311253245#shpCntId

My Question is

1. What type of Hard drives can be used in that type of product. I mean can i use SATA drives in there
2. What type of Hardware is required to use it. I mean if I join hard drives from front then they must be somehow copnnected to server and then from that stoarge server what type of cable is required to join to my window server.
3. What is HDD caddy they talk about in description

Comment: *Questions and answers about this item No questions or answers have been posted about this item. Ask a question* Maybe you should make use of the *Ask a question* feature on eBay.

Comment: All you have to do is read the item description, i.e. "
Note: No rack rails included. The HDD caddy's are SATA to FIBRE conversation."  I HDD "caddy" is the physical,removable, cage that holds the drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Usually SATA 3.5" HDD.
2. HDD Caddy is used to connect your HDD to the server. The HDD Caddy will convert your HDD into signal that's used by the server. Further details, look for the manuals or contact the seller.

   > The HDD caddy's are SATA to FIBRE conversation.
3. See #2 & [HDD Caddy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDD_caddy)

Comment: Thanks for that. As u said we need hdd caddy to connect to server. u mean that i put SATA disk in caddy and tdhen that caddy in that storage server but then how will my  IBM server detect those 10 SATA drives attached to that storage server,. will there be one cable connecting IBM server to that Hitachi storage server. what type oc cable will that be

Comment: Yes. When you slide it all in, there are connectors inside.

Comment: thanks for that , Actually i am bit confused. is that storage server all complete by itself. i mean once 10 drives are attached to it then  how will my other computers access that. is there any wire i need to connect to my DESKTOP so that it can access those 10 drives

Comment: @Donkey I would go to Hatachi's website and download the manual to figure that out. Ususally those kinds of enclosures will not have any kind of connectors you would see  on a desktop computer (like [Fiber Channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibre_Channel)). But I have not checked the manual yet, it may just be eSATA.

Comment: It is only a hard drive array enclosure where you install your drives and provides power to all the drives. It probably isn't usable without another server hooked up to it. What I think is this is one of the subsystem from a whole data storage system which include multiple parts that looks like this. Contact the manufacturer for further details.